# Get value from more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code where I get the 'value' from one table for the month of April

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END),2) Col1,
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN value END),2) Col2
FROM tableforapril
WHERE 
  id IN ('1','2') 
  and DATE( from_unixtime( t_stamp / 1000 ) ) 
        BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-01'
  and value is not null
GROUP BY
  DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp / 1000 )),
  HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp / 1000 ))
```

But the problem I have is i have more than one table, I have another table for march 
wherein i also need to get the 'value' column from that table.

If i do that timestamp like:

```
and DATE( from_unixtime( t_stamp / 1000 ) ) 
        BETWEEN '2014-03-31 and '2014-04-01'
```

I would need to get the 'value' column from the march table and april table.
Where the output would look something like this:

```
t_stamp         |   Col1    |   Col2
2014-04-01 3:00 AM  |   1.23    |   2.33
2014-04-01 5:00 AM  |   4.55    |   5.13
2014-03-31 1:00 PM  |   12.33   |   2.00
2014-03-31 2:00 PM  |   5.12    |   3.99
```

Col1 and Col2 column are both from the march and april table. The tables I'm using are separated by month, both tables have their value t_stamp. Unfortunately, 
I can't edit the tables that I'm using as I'm not allowed to.

On my project, the user will select the t_stamp based on the dropdown list

Comment: @hear...In you example output, is Col1 from the April table and Col2 from the March table?  And where is the value from t_stamp coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two separate tables there's no way to query both unless you join them and since you've provided no relational data point, your only option would be union. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableforapril 
WHERE....
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tableformarch
WHERE ...
```

Another solution maybe simply returning the contents from both tables:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2 FROM tableforapril a, tableformarch b
```